# How many vertical containers to grow food for one person?

Tags: vegetables, containers, food-crops, sustainability

The diet would only be plant based, by vertical garden I mean something like this:
[image]

But with vegetables instead of flowers and a tower that's 3-5 levels

How many of these "towers" would be enough for one person?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question please - its impossible to answer as it is because we need to know which vegetables you wish to grow. This sort of set up is unlikely to be much use for most,  other than possibly strawberries

Comment: No one kind in particular? I want it to be as varied as possible

Comment: When you say "grow food for one person", do you mean to supplement store or market bought vegetables? Or do mean to grow all the vegetables you're going to eat?  If the second choice, then it would also depend on the amount of vegetables you'd normally eat and if there are any you dislike and wouldn't grow.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad to get anything other than a general answer. You've said you want the vegetables you grow to be as varied as possible, but haven't named any you want to grow. However, frankly, the kind of arrangement shown in your photograph simply isn't going to work for growing most vegetables. The plants shown are merely summer bedding type plants, just temporary planting - primarily petunia and a couple of pelargoniums, and it'll look okay for about 3 months, till the petunias get leggy.

Strawberries might work, some of the dwarf bush tomatoes might work, but, as your tower of pots gets higher, the pots of necessity must be smaller, and unless you just want to put something like chives in a small pot on top, none of the pots above the second one will be big enough. Even lettuce planted round the outside of the biggest pot won't be able to bush out properly because of the obstruction in the centre caused by the next pot.